# How to implement similar to sscanf method in Objective-C for NSString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have `NSString data =@"name@some1.some2.com:12345";`

I want to do the same action like `sscanf` does in `C`

```
char val1[512];
char val2[512];
char val3[512];

val1[0]=val2[0]=val3[0]='\0';

sscanf(data,"%[^@]@%[^:]:%511s",val1,val2,val3);
```

I get `val1=name`, `val2=some1.com`, `val3=`12345`

And how to implement `sprintf(new_val, "%s:%s",val1,val2);` like

just in Objective-C.
I know Obj-C handles basic C form but Im interesting to use mostly `NSString` to prevent convert from `char` to `NSString`.

so it should be:

```
NSString val1=nil;
NSString val2=nil;
NSString val3=nil;
   ....
```

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099612/sscanf-equivalent-in-objective-c