# Calculate two values in a string separately

Tags: objective-c

I need to identify two values in the string 'legCentimetres' separately

an example value of which is:-

'15-18'

to apply inches calculation and then put back together. What I have done only seems to calculate the first bit, at the moment it is coming out as:-

15cm / 5.9in

but should look like:-

15-18cm / 5.9-7.1in

What changes should I make in the code below to make this work?

```
- (NSString *)textForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath isTitle:(BOOL)isTitle {
    NSString *result = @"";
    double legCentimetres = [self.animal.legSpan doubleValue];
    double legInches = lcm / 2.54;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            result = (isTitle)? @"Habitat" : self.animal.habitat;
            break;
        case 1:
            result = (isTitle)? @"Leg Span" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dcm / %.1fin", (int)legCentimetres, legInches];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This answer should get you there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10099661/1180785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)textForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath isTitle:(BOOL)isTitle {
    NSString *result = @"";
    double legCentimetresMin = [[[self.animal.legSpan componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    double legCentimetresMax = [[[self.animal.legSpan componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
    double legInchesMin = legCentimetresMin / 2.54;
    double legInchesMax = legCentimetresMax / 2.54;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            result = (isTitle)? @"Habitat" : self.animal.habitat;
            break;
        case 1:
            result = (isTitle)? @"Leg Span" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%dcm / %.1f-%.1fin", (int)legCentimetresMin, (int)legCentimetresMax, legInchesMin, legInchesMax];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're a bloody genius! First time! awesome work, thanks for your help

Comment: Seems silly to do `componentsSeparated...` twice.  And the calc of legInchesMin/Max should be moved to inside case 1, since case 0 presumably doesn't even guarantee that "legSpan" exists.

Comment: Why split the same string twice? Call `componentsSeparatedByString:` just once and store the result in an array so you can access each part as needed.

Comment: As a follow up, I did it twice for legibility for the person asking the question. It would be more logical to store the components in a variable and then access them.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good way, although you could probably scale it down slightly. I'm taking the legspan and splitting it into two numbers (the range in centimetres), then enumerating through those centimetres, converting each to inches. From there, I am adding them to an array where I can later convert them into an NSString.

```
- (NSString *)textForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath isTitle:(BOOL)isTitle {
    NSString *result = @"";
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            result = (isTitle)? @"Habitat" : self.animal.habitat;
            break;
        case 1 {
            NSString *legSpan = self.animal.legSpan;
            NSArray *centimetres = [legSpan componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
            NSMutableArray *inches = [NSMutableArray array];
            NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            [fmt setMaximumFractionDigits:1];
            [centimetres enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                [inches addObject:[fmt stringFromNumber:@([obj doubleValue] / 2.54)]];
            }];
            NSString *inchString = [[inches componentsJoinedByString:@"-"] stringByAppendingString:@"in"];
            NSString *cmString = [legSpan stringByAppendingString:@"cm"];

            result = (isTitle)? @"Leg Span" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dcm / %.1fin", cmString, inchString];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Looks good! now just have to work out how to plant in my code.. I've updated my code to show full section

Comment: But you shouldn't calculate legCentimeters unless you're taking case 1.